# Open image from sdcard

Tags: android

I want to open image saved on the sdcard and let the user choose under which application, they would like to open the image. How can I do that?Thanks
Below code gives the option to open with internet which is not what I want.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/myapp/2014-04-21.png")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the data type. Try this instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/myapp/2014-04-21.png"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It does give the option to view image using image viewers but couldn't display my image saying there is no image. I checked the image in is sdcard under my folder. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It works now. There was initially space when I was saving .png image, that's why it wasn't displaying anything. Thanks